# Quatro condições diferentes usando awk if (unix)

Tags: if, unix, awk

Olá preciso fazer de um comando awk if usando 4 condições diferentes juntas, exemplo do meu input apenas para poucas linhas (tenho um input com milhares de linhas)

```
chr17_30  1
chr1_72   0
chr1_46   2
chr1_47   -1
chr1_48   1
```

Output desejável

```
chr17_30  1 AB
chr1_72   0 AA
chr1_46   2 BB
chr1_47  -1 NN
chr1_48   1 AB
```

Como faço isso? Só conseguir fazer para uma condição usando o awk if. Pode ser outro comando também.

obrigada
Clarissa

Comment: como determinas a coluna adicionada? donde vem os (AB,AA,...)? Que tentaste?

Comment: oi @JJoao esta codificação é pré-estabelecida para meus dados de genética. O código 1 significa que meu animal é AB, 2 é BB, -1 é dado perdido (NN) e 0 é AA. O que fiz foi usar o comando: cat input.txt | awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t"}; BEGIN{OFS="\t"}; {if ($2==1) {print $0,"AB"} else{print $0, "\t"}}' | awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t"}; BEGIN{OFS="\t"}; {if ($2==0) {print $0,"AA"} else{print $0, "\t"}}'  | head
 Mas neste caso a codificação fica em colunas separadas e eu quero tudo na mesma coluna.

Answer (score 3):

```
awk 'BEGIN{split("NN,AA,AB,BB",a,",")}  {print $0,a[$2+2]}' input.txt
```

Explicação:

- No início, `split("NN,AA,AB,BB",a,",")` define um array "a" com `a[1]=NN`, `a[2]=AA`, `a[3]=AB`, etc. Repare-se que os indices estão "2" abaixo do campo `$1`
- portando é necessário `a[$2+2]` para obter a correspondência pretendida.

Comment: Desculpa mas não entendi o comando. Eu uso isso para unir as colunas que criei com AA, AB, NN e BB? O que seria o $2+2?

Comment: Tomando por exemplo o caso da linha 4, `$2+2` vai buscar o valor contido na segunda coluna do input (`-1`) e soma-lhe 2 (obtendo 1); `a[1]` é `NN`  portanto escreve `chr1_47  -1 NN`.